# Python: Combine Multiline to Singleline

Tags: python, regex

I have input file with data:

```
2015-06-05 16:22:10 Payload-Line-1

Payload-Line-2 

2015-06-05 16:22:11 Payload-Line-1

Payload-Line-2

Payload-Line-3

2015-06-05 16:22:12 Payload-Line-1
```

I try to make out file like:

```
2015-06-05 16:22:10 Payload-Line-1
Payload-Line-2 

2015-06-05 16:22:11 Payload-Line-1
Payload-Line-2
Payload-Line-3

2015-06-05 16:22:12 Payload-Line-1
```

This is multiline start from same regex `\d{1,4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}`, but i can not do this

Any python experts can help me?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions. The first is a bit limited, but achieves the output without the use of regular expressions. Where `text` holds your sample text as shown in your question.

```
print text.replace("\n\n", "\n").replace("2015-", "\n2015-").strip()

print re.sub(r"(?!^)(\d{4}-)", r"\n\1", text.replace("\n\n", "\n"))
```

Both of these give the following output:

```
2015-06-05 16:22:10 Payload-Line-1
Payload-Line-2 

2015-06-05 16:22:11 Payload-Line-1
Payload-Line-2
Payload-Line-3

2015-06-05 16:22:12 Payload-Line-1
```

Tested using Python 2.7